# MileStoneUtils apex class requires code coverage. Stops at 57%

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests, casemilestone

Working off of the code provided here https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.entitlements_milestones_trigger.htm&type=5

The test class does not cover required coverage specially the if condition in the below code. Any inputs and help is appreciated.

***Apex Class***

```
public class MilestoneUtils {
    public static void completeMilestone(List<Id> caseIds,String milestoneName, DateTime complDate) {  

        List<CaseMilestone> cmsToUpdate = [select Id, completionDate
                                           from CaseMilestone cm
                                           where caseId in :caseIds and 
                                           cm.MilestoneType.Name=:milestoneName 
                                           and completionDate = null limit 1];

        if (cmsToUpdate.isEmpty() == false){
            for (CaseMilestone cm : cmsToUpdate){
                cm.completionDate = complDate;
            }
            update cmsToUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

*****Here is the test class method*****

```
 @isTest static void updateMileStnComplDateTest(){
        List<Account> acts = new List<Account>();
        Account myAcc = new Account(Name='TestAct', phone='1001231234');
        acts.add(myAcc);
        
        Account busAcc = new Account(Name = 'TestForMS', phone='4567890999');
        acts.add(busAcc);
        insert acts;

        Contact cont = new Contact(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'LastName', 
                                   phone='4567890999', accountid = busAcc.id);
        insert(cont);

        SlaProcess sla = [SELECT Id FROM SlaProcess WHERE isActive = true LIMIT 1];   
        
        Entitlement entl = new Entitlement(Name='TestEntitlement', AccountId=busAcc.Id, 
                                          slaProcessId = sla.Id);
        insert entl;
        
        
        List<Case> cases = new List<Case>{};
        Case c = new Case(Subject = 'Test Case with Entitlement ', 
                          EntitlementId = entl.Id, ContactId = cont.Id,
                          Status = 'Closed', SlaStartDate = date.today() - 5 
                          );
        cases.add(c);            
        insert cases;

        List<Id> caseIds = new List<Id>();
        for (Case cL : cases){
             caseIds.add(cL.Id);
        }
        milestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds, 'Resolution Time', System.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is testing if Case Milestones were found for the case Id(s) and Milestone Types passed to the `completeMilestone` method. If it is not being covered, that means no such milestones were found.  The sample unit test code provided in the help document assumes you have an entitlement process that will create a Milestone of type 'Resolution Time' on the Case created during the test.  You may need to modify this to match your actual entitlement process.